# Want the results in the same order as the input

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this

```
SELECT NUM,
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4,
       col5,
       col6
FROM   (SELECT NUM,
               col1,
               col2
        FROM   (SELECT a.mid  AS NUM,
                       a.col1 AS col1,
                       a.col2 AS col2
                FROM   tbl a (nolock)
                WHERE  a.mid IN ( '09-404811,10-433495,10-433575,10-423789' )) AS MainQuery
               UNPIVOT ( LabelValue
                       FOR Label IN (NUM,
                                     col1,
                                     col2 ) ) AS UnpvtQuery) LT
       INNER JOIN #SetItemsTable tt
               ON tt.col7 = LT.col1
WHERE  LT.NUM IN ( '09-404811,10-433495,10-433575,10-423789' )
ORDER  BY Charindex(NUM, '09-404811,10-433495,10-433575,10-423789')
```

This is only a representation of the original query. The list of values supplied for IN() will be approx 400+.

The problem I have with this query is
   `ORDER BY CHARINDEX(NUM,'09-404811,10-433495,10-433575,10-423789')` is taking almost 25 secs to execute. Otherwise the rest of the query takes only 6 sec.
  I am using `CHARINDEX()` because I need the result in the same order in which the values inside IN() appear.

How can i make this work efficiently.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use an efficient splitting function. Whether it will be significantly faster than your current approach remains to be seen...

Comment: `LT.NUM IN ( '09-404811,10-433495,10-433575,10-423789' )` won't do what you want anyway. Is that a typo? Should be `LT.NUM IN ( '09-404811','10-433495','10-433575','10-423789' )`.

Comment: @Martin you are right. It's a typo.  Actually I am using a splitting function which accept a single comma-separated list instead of individual strings.

Comment: So get the split function to return an index column as well as the value, change to a join rather than in, and order by the index.

Comment: As per the answer in the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

I would select the inner query to a temporary table first, then you can query and order/group by however you need to. I would avoid trying to use Charindex because it will need to go through all the values returned.